# What’s the Java Shebang for OS X?

Tags: java, development, bbedit

I just started using TextWrangler in place of Eclipse for writing Java programs. I found a script for testing Java programs in Terminal, but I’d like to handle everything right through TextWrangler. What’s the Java shebang for OS X? Or is there a Java shebang which is specifically for TextWrangler?

Comment: You are aware that you need to compile the source before you can run it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple wrapper script that effectively can work as a Java shebang on OS X and Linux:

```
# /* ------- build and run wrapper script for Java -----------------------------
TMP=$(mktemp -d)
tail -c +3 ${0} > ${TMP}/$(basename ${0})
cd ${TMP} && javac $(basename ${0}) && java $(basename ${0%.*}) ${@:1}
RV=${?} ; cd - > /dev/null ; rm -rf ${TMP}
exit ${RV}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

public class example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

However, as pointed out in the comments this is technically not a "shebang", but it comes pretty close in terms of functionality.

Comment: This is no shebang.

Comment: @MaxRied technically yes but it is a shell file I think not on mac currently.

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /usr/bin/java  --source=11
```

The --source argument is required.  If the source argument is omitted the following error message will be produced.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

Here is a complete example

```
#! /usr/bin/java  --source=11
public class HelloWorld  
{  
   public static void main(final String[] args)  
   {  
      System.console().printf("Hello world");  
   }  
}
```

Comment: Note that this will only work with Java 11 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

The java executable is /usr/bin/java

So shebang is

```
#! /usr/bin/java
```

However a java program is usually in more than one java file and so you need a build system e.g. ant, gradle, maven, sbt .......

If you are just learning and not doing a full release to other users I would stick to Eclipse (or another IDE e.g. Intellij) which can also package for other users

Comment: I tried that, but I got this result: Error: Could not find or load main class .Users.jfblagden.Desktop.PiesTest.java

Comment: The command line gets more cpomplex thus learn a build system or stick with Eclipse. you can get this one file to work with parameters to the shebang but not really worth it easier to write a shell script to call java